# Rails - Force window scroll position to top when a new partial is rendered

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app where I am changing the content dynamically by rendering partials

```
<% content_for(:content) do -%>
    <%= render partial: "registrations/partials/#{@current_user.patient_metadata.registration_step}" %>
<% end -%>
```

The partials change after submitting the form, which is in the partial.

Problem is that when the new partial is rendered, the scroll position is still half way down, where it was in the previous partial after completing the form.

I have tried adding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0)
})
```

and tested that it fires after the page is refreshed, but the scroll position is still not at the top when the new partial is rendered.

How can I make sure that when a new partial is rendered, the scroll position is set back at the top?

Comment: What do you mean `The partials change after submitting the form` ? Does the form submit via AJAX ?
Anyway, the partial rendered at the server side, but the JS executed at client side, so there isn't any thing like `when a new partial is rendered, JS executes`

Comment: Can you add the code which is responsible for rendering the dynamic partials?

Answer (score 0):

If change happen through `ajax call` use

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   //other datas
   success: function(html){
      // Your other codes
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
   }
});
```

If it's through server call

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
```